# The point $a \in X$ is smooth then there is only one irreducible component of $X$ meeting $a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

I am reading Gathmann's note on Algebraic Geometry and there is a remark that I really don't understand in the chapter 10. First I recall a result that is, apprently, needed to understand the remark.

> **Proposition 2.28** Let $X$ be a non-empty irreducible affine variety. If $f \in A(X)$ is non-zero every irreducible component of $V(f)$ has codimension $1$ in $X$ (and hence dimension $\text{dim}~ X - 1$ by a previous result).

And now the remark.

> **Remark 10.10** (b) It is a result of commutative algebra that a regular local ring as in (a) (here he means $\mathcal O_{X, a}$, the *stalk* of $\mathcal O_X$ at $a \in X$ an affine variety, which is a regular local ring iff $a$ is smooth by a previous discussion) is always an integral domain. Translating this into geometry as in the previous proposition (he means the above one), this yields the intuitively obvious statement that a variety is locally irreducible at every smooth point $a$, i.e. that $X$ has only one irreducible component meeting $a$. (...)

I really don't understand how we can translate the fact that $\mathcal O_{X, a}$ is an integral domain to the geometry and deduce that there is only one irreducible component of $X$ that meets $a$. I don't even have the intuition of this result (which is suppose to be obvious according to him)... Could one of you enlighten me on this?

Comment: Your title doesn't quite match your body - the result isn't an iff, it's a single implication.

Comment: Right, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim**: the prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_{X,a}$ are in bijection with the irreducible subvarieties of $X$ passing through $a$.

**Proof**: we can start by looking at an open affine neighborhood $Y$ of $a$ inside $X$. Then by remark 2.9 in the current 2021 version of Gathmann's notes, irreducible subvarieties of $Y$ are in bijection with prime ideals of $A(Y)$. Next, by lemma/definition 3.19, $\mathcal{O}_{X,a}$ is the localization of $A(Y)$ at the ideal corresponding to $a$ - as the prime ideals of a localization are the prime ideals not meeting the set of elements we invert, we have that the prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_{X,a}$ are precisely the prime ideals of $A(Y)$ which correspond to irreducible subvarieties passing through $a$. $\blacksquare$

Now we're almost done: irreducible components are maximal irreducible closed subsets, so they correspond to minimal prime ideals. As a domain has a unique minimal prime, $(0)$, if $\mathcal{O}_{X,a}$ is a domain, $a$ is on a unique irreducible component of $X$. Since regular local rings are domains, this shows what you're after.

Comment: Nice, thank you for your explanation, but why is he saying that this result is intuitively obvious ? Is there a geometrical interpretation that I am totally missing ?

Comment: The condition of being smooth at a point should mean that locally around that point, our variety behaves like a manifold. No intersection of multiple components behaves like a manifold near that intersection.

Comment: why it doesn't behave like a manifold near the intersection?

Comment: Draw a picture! For example, consider the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis in the plane.